# Using multiple basemaps with masking/clipping?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, display, representation, basemap

Is there a way to limit a basemap to within a boundary in arcmap 10?

I am working on a project within San Joaquin county in California.  I want the areas surrounding the county to be displayed with a light grey basemap with minimal details.  Within the county itself, however, I want to use a more detailed basemap that has the information I am trying to portray.

Is there a way to add a second basemap but have it be limited to the county boundaries?

Comment: I am not sure if it will work or not, but you could use the data frame clipping option.  This allows you to clip certain layers to a polygon extent.  It is located in Data Frame Properties -> Data Frame tab at the bottom.

Comment: @dklassen Yes, that will work, although clipping applies by default to everything so you'd have to go in and exclude every other added layer so it applied only to the one basemap layer. I would suggest you post as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the data frame clipping option. This allows you to clip certain layers to a polygon extent. It is located in Data Frame Properties -> Data Frame tab at the bottom.  By default, it applies this clip to all layers, so you might have to go in and only select the layers you want clipped.